# In ember.js, what's the difference between mixin and extend?

Tags: ember.js

What's is the difference between mixin and extend, when to use each one?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I wrote [this article about Ember.Object](http://www.cerebris.com/blog/2012/03/06/understanding-ember-object/) which explains the differences in detail. Essentially, use `extend` to create a new class from a base class and use mixins to separate lateral concerns that you may want to include in any number of classes / objects.  Mixins can be included in classes via `extend` or objects via `create`.

Answer (score 3):

A mixin is a special kind of multiple inheritance. There are two main situations where mixins are used:

1. You want to provide a lot of optional features for a class.
2. You want to use one particular feature in a lot of different
   classes.